# How to change Android Navigation drawer header's color dynamically

Tags: android

I'm new to Android and got stuck at changing color of the `NavigationDrawer` header's color. I want to dynamically change the color of [this part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiLb6.png) in the drawer (it's defined by a layout file named nav_header_main.xml, automatically generated by Android studio), I found many ways to change it in the **xml** files, but I want to change the color according to my color picker's returned value, I've tried `.setBackgroundColor`, which won't work at all, and the only one seemed working, which is `.setBackground`, requires `Drawable` while I only have an int value of the color, anyone knows how to solve this? Please help me, thanks!
(Btw all the layout files and the construction codes are generated by Android studio in case you're curious about the structure of this drawer)

Comment: You can change header layout design of NavigationView from layout itself app:headerlayout of your xml

Comment: I know that would work, but I want to change the color dynamically, the color should be set by a color picker function that I wrote, so changing xml file won't work for my case, any other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the header from within the `NavigationView` that you have in your layout - trying to access the header layout directly will not work because it it isn't directly inflated into your activity, whereas the `NavigationView` is.

```
int color = Color.CYAN;
View navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View header = navView.getHeaderView(0);
header.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

Comment: I've tried it but there's not getHeaderView method when I put nav_view.getHeaderView(0) I guess I put the wrong resource ID in the findViewById part, which Id should I refer to then? thanks!

Comment: Oh, I've figured out the resource id now, I can successfully get the header id, but setBackGroundColor doesn't seem to work for it, the color won't change, any ideas why?

Comment: Can't make guesses without seeing your layout files and code. Can you edit your first post to add both relevant layout files and the portion of code to find the views and set the color?

Comment: Nevermind, I have solved the problem, I found the id of nav_view and changed the color by using setBackground(new colorDrawable), thanks for the help though.